Authentication in websocket
I have an express application, which serves some api endpoints and a websocket. Web sockets have rooms and on every message it inserts a message to mongodb.
wsServer.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
  const params = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  const token = params.token;

  if (!token) {
    ws.close(1008, "token required");
  }

  ws.on("message", (message) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(data.room);
    switch (data.type) {
      case "join":
        if (!rooms[data.room]) {
          rooms[data.room] = [];
        }
        rooms[data.room].push(ws);
        ws.room = data.room;
        broadcast(ws.room, `User joined room ${ws.room}`);
        break;

      case "message":
        const date = new Date();
        insertMessage(
          "data",
          {
            day: date.getDate() + 1,
            month: date.getMonth() + 1,
            year: date.getFullYear(),
            hour: date.getHours(),
            minute: date.getMinutes(),
            second: date.getSeconds(),
          },
          ws.room,
          data.message
        );
        broadcast(ws.room, data.message);
        break;
    }
  });

  ws.on("close", () => {
    if (ws.room && rooms[ws.room]) {
      rooms[ws.room] = rooms[ws.room].filter((client) => client !== ws);
      broadcast(ws.room, `User left room ${ws.room}`);
    }
  });
});

For my frontend, I am using React and have this code :
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from "react-use-websocket";

const socketURL = "ws://localhost:8080";

const Chat = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messageHistory, setMessageHistory] = useState([]);
  const { room_category } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  /// THIS WHOLE THING IS FOR WEB SOCKET \\\
  const { sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(
    `${socketURL}?token=${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    {
      onOpen: () => {
        sendMessage(
          JSON.stringify({
            type: "join",
            room: room_category,
          })
        );
      },
      shouldReconnect: (closeEvent) => true,
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastMessage !== null) {
      const data = JSON.parse(lastMessage.data);
      setMessageHistory((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, data.message]);
    }
  }, [lastMessage]);

  const connectionStatus = {
    0: "Connecting",
    1: "Open",
    2: "Closing",
    3: "Closed",
  }[readyState];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (connectionStatus === "Closed") {
      navigate("/home");
    }
  }, [connectionStatus]);

  const handleSendMessage = useCallback(() => {
    if (input.trim()) {
      sendMessage(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "message",
          message: input,
        })
      );
      setInput("");
    }
  }, [input, sendMessage]);

  /// THIS WHOLE THING IS FOR WEB SOCKET \\\

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Room: {room_category}</h2>
      <div>Status: {connectionStatus}</div>
      <div>
        {messageHistory.map((msg, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{msg}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleSendMessage()}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;

I also have a function to find a user from the db
Async/Await one :
exports.findUser = async ({ id, username, name }) => {
  let query;
  //checking which data is providedf to set this data to query
  if (id) {
    query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
  }
  if (username) {
    query = { username };
  }
  if (name) {
    query = { name };
  }
  //finding user with setted query
  const user = await usersCollection.findOne(query);
  return user;
};

And regular one :
exports.findUser_ = ({ id, username, name }) => {
  let query;

  // checking which data is provided to set this data to query
  if (id) {
    query = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
  }
  if (username) {
    query = { username };
  }
  if (name) {
    query = { name };
  }

  // finding user with set query
  return usersCollection
    .findOne(query)
    .then((user) => {
      return user;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error finding user:", error);
      throw error;
    });
};

When I try to run async/await function in the websocket connection I get unexpected actions. When I try to make it with traditional Promise.then method I only get one user every time. How can I verify user using jwt?

do you have any existing jwt token in req.header or params?

I have it on params

only problem is to get user from database
